# Oracle Apex Apps. Sending data to two tables on submit

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have two tables, HELP_PROBLEMS and HELP_SOLUTIONS.

HELP_PROBLEMS has a number of different fields, including PROBLEM_ID, SOLUTION_ID, PROBLEM_DESC etc.

HELP_SOLUTIONS has just SOLUTION_ID and SOLUTION_DESC.

I'm trying to build form that when you view the edit form of a problem, you can add the solution in a form below it.
In my mind, when I hit the button Add Solution (submit), it creates the new row in HELP_SOLUTIONS, and adds the SOLUTION_ID to the current row in HELP_PROBLEMS. (and update a few other things but trying to keep this as basic as possible).

Is this at all possible? I thought the 'master form' might work but I couldn't seem to sort it out as planned.

Thanks,
C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a pl/sql block that inserts a value in two different tables.
create a page process and select pl/sql
then try something like

begin

--insert into help_problems
--insert into help_solutions

end;

Comment: @Coffee just shout if you still having problems.

Comment: Thanks mate, just trying it out now, will let you know how it goes =)

Comment: Can't get the insert and update statements to work. I'm running just the INSERT into help_solutions, and it works, but doesn't insert the data in my fields, i.e. :P12_SOLUTION_DESC.